# How can I add a text ("https://") to a string that does not start with https:// but instead www?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I recieve data and my label (named website) has both urls that start with and without https, so when a label starts with www and not the http I wish to add that to the string so that the link will work to those who hasnt put https in their url-link.

This is what I currently have:

```
URLButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { 

    Uri outvalue;

    if(Uri.TryCreate(website.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out outvalue))
    {
        Device.OpenUri(outvalue);
    }
};
```

With this current code the URL's that does not have http but www instead in the beginning will not be clickable.

So if a website URL does not have the https (like some of them dont) I need to add the https manually in the code but I am not sure how I could do it.

```
If (website.text != (start with http))
"https://" + website.text

else 

 website.text = website.text or something like that
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more elegant solution would be to use the `UriBuilder` class (which can also add a missing `www.`):

```
URLButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    Uri value = new UriBuilder(website.Text).Uri;
    website.Text = value.AbsoluteUri;
    Device.OpenUri(value);
}
```

Comment: indeed more elegant. nice solution

Answer (score 2):

Brute force:

```
if (!website.Text.StartsWith("https://") ) {
                website.Text= "https://" + website.Text;
            }
```

Would probably want more robust validation depending on possible input permutations.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, what you want to do is convert something like `www.google.se` to `http:\\www.google.se`?

```
if(!website.Text.StartsWith("http://"))
{
   website.Text ="http://" + website.Text;
}
```